# WebFlux + freemarker query params not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker, spring-webflux

No query parameters when I try to make a post request for /registration, there are no values that I enter from the form,

In spring mvc default app that works, but in webflux app there is no query params from input form when

I make post request

registration.ftl:

```
<form action="/registration" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> User Name : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Password : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input  type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.getToken()}"/>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-20">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Handlers:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> registrationPost(ServerRequest serverRequest){
    Set<String> stringSet = serverRequest.queryParams().keySet();
    for(String s:stringSet){
        logger.info(s+": "+serverRequest.queryParams().get(s));
    }
    String username = (String) serverRequest.queryParam("username").get();
    String password = (String) serverRequest.queryParam("password").get();
    User user = new User();
    user.setUser_avatar("default.jpg");
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
    Mono<User> userFromDb = userService.findByUserName(user.getUsername());
    AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    userFromDb.subscribe(u->{
        if(u!=null) atomicBoolean.set(true);
    });
    if(atomicBoolean.get()){
        logger.info("user from db exists");
        return ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
    } else {
        Mono<User> save = userService.save(user);
        save.subscribe(u->{
            logger.info("user successfully created");
        });
        return ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("/login")).build();
    }

}
```

[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qylu3.png)

websecurity and webmvc configs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.server")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration {

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
        ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    return http.csrf()
            .and().authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/login", "/registration").permitAll()
            .anyExchange()
            .authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .and().build();

    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebFlux
@Configuration
public class WebMvc implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMvc.class);

    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("classpath:/templates/");
        return configurer;
    }


    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.freeMarker().suffix(".ftl");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("file:///" + uploadPath + "/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/").addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/");
    }
}
```

```
    @Configuration
public class MainRouter {
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> mainRoute(MainHandler mainHandler){

    RequestPredicate get = GET("/news");

    RequestPredicate login = GET("/login");

    RequestPredicate friends = GET("/friends");

    RequestPredicate registrationGet = GET("/registration");

    RequestPredicate registrationPost = POST("/registration");


    return route(get, mainHandler::news)
            .andRoute(login, mainHandler::login)
            .andRoute(friends, mainHandler::friends)
            .andRoute(registrationGet, mainHandler::registrationGet).andRoute(registrationPost, mainHandler::registrationPost);
    }



}
```

Comment: Please add your configuration. It doesn't look like it is failing on this method but rather the Spirng Security classes.

Comment: websecurity config and webmvc config: http://code.re/nua

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information. I'm not going to visit links to get a full picture of your issue.

Comment: added websecurity and webmvc configs

Comment: Where is the mapping for your handler? Also just wondering are you using plain Spring or Spring Boot?

Comment: added mainrouter this mappings, i'm using spring boot

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot you don't need the webflux configuration, that is added automatically as well as the freemarker stuff. That being said you are trying to obtain query parameters however it is form data. Instead use `request.bodToMono(User.class)`. Which should bind the parameters to a `User` object. form-data is't query parameters.

Comment: thank you a lot, i understand, i should not use serverRequest.queryParam(), i should use serverRequest.formData(), thanks